# How to build a data frame using pandas where attributes are arranged?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a data frame in pandas that look like this:

```
Id  Name    Gender  Math    Science English
1   Ram     Male    98      92      80
2   Hari    Male    30      40      23
3   Gita    Female  60      65      77
4   Sita    Female  50      45      55
5   Shyam   Male    80      88      82
```

I wrote quote in python like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Name':['Ram','Hari','Gita','Sita','Shyam'],'Gender':['Male','Male','Female','Female','Male'],'Math':[98,30,60,50,80],'Science':[92,40,65,45,88],'English':[80,23,77,55,82]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)
```

It gave me output like this:

```
    English  Gender  Id  Math   Name  Science
0       80    Male   1    98    Ram       92
1       23    Male   2    30   Hari       40
2       77  Female   3    60   Gita       65
3       55  Female   4    50   Sita       45
4       82    Male   5    80  Shyam       88
```

How do I remove the first column with no attribute and also arrange attributes in such a way that is given in the question?
I want Id, Name, Gender, Math, Science, English. Thanks

Comment: It's producing desired output

Comment: but the attributes are not arranged

Comment: i want Name infront of English attribute and where did the first column come from?

Comment: 1st column is an index for your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want index, you can set it by unique column like `Id`.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Name':['Ram','Hari','Gita','Sita','Shyam'],'Gender':['Male','Male','Female','Female','Male'],'Math':[98,30,60,50,80],'Science':[92,40,65,45,88],'English':[80,23,77,55,82]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index('Id', inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
     Name  Gender  Math  Science  English
Id                                       
1     Ram    Male    98       92       80
2    Hari    Male    30       40       23
3    Gita  Female    60       65       77
4    Sita  Female    50       45       55
5   Shyam    Male    80       88       82
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to create directly the DataFrame instead of passing by "d"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 4, 7, 10], etc...})
```

Then use set_index to fix your Id as it :

```
df.set_index('Id')
```

Comment: Thank you very much